# Align to right side of relative layout does not seem to work

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to have 2 textviews one next to the other to the right side of the parent container.
Something like:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  (parent container)  
|               TextView2 TextView1 |  
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The following does not work but I can't understand why

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="100dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TEXTVIEW-1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:text="TEXTVIEW-2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: The 100dp is only just to show the problem

**UPDATE:**
After removing android:layout_alignParentTop="true" and android:layout_alignParentRight="true" I get:

[image]

Comment: remove "layout_alignParentRight='true'" from the textView2 xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your second TextView, use `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1"` and remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="100dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TEXTVIEW-1"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:text="TEXTVIEW-2"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

**What it actually does is:**

When you used `android:alignParentRight="true"` in both of the textViews, It will place both the textViews to the right side overlapping each other.

So on adding it to only one textView it will align it to the right side only. And then adding `toLeftOf` will place it to the left of first textView.

> UPDATE:

I didn't find any documentation for the question how is the priority given to RelativeLayout. But, I dig into the RelativeLayout.java file to find out. It was a bit hard to understand.

So I tried to play with the options and what i found :

- If you apply `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` the priority will be given to **android:layout_alignParentStart**
- If you apply `android:layout_toStartOf="@id/view2"` and `android:layout_toEndOf="@id/view2"` the priority will be given to **android:layout_toEndOf**
- If you apply `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` and `android:layout_toStartOf="@id/view1"` the priority will be given to **android:layout_alignParentStart**
- If you apply `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` , `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_toStartOf="@id/view1"`

  Then the priority will be given in order

  ```
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"   //1 High
   android:layout_toStartOf="@id/view1"     //2 Medium
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"   //3 Low
  ```

  So, it means `android:layout_centerHorizontal` will work only if `android:layout_alignParentStart` and `android:layout_toStartOf` will not be there.

Hope it is clear now. 
I would love to read about the priorities if someone finds the documentation of this.

Comment: Both show up now but TextView-1 now is displayed vertically. I mean each letter in a separate line

Comment: It is because both of your text views are getting more width than your container that is set to 100dp. Increase the container size from 100dp. And if you want to hide and show only sigle line and hide the overflowing content will show the method for that

Comment: So although I have set the left of it is ignored to give priority to the align parent right?

Comment: @Jim Absolutely. It will give priority to `alignParentRight` . And it you have only this 2 textviews inside LinearLayout, you can remove RelativeLayout  and and set `android:gravity="end"` to your LinearLayout (oreinetation:horizontal) with the same result.

Comment: But with that way I would need to define them in reverse order right?

Comment: Yes, As mentioned textViews order in the question, you need to alter the textViews. It will be same effect like left and right aligned text in any text editors.

Comment: How did you know about the priority of align parent right? Is it in the documentation?

Comment: Because I am trying to improve my knowledge on this

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. So basically to get better in layouts we need to dig in the source code?

Comment: To get better in anything we need to dig in the source? Shouldn't we?

Answer (score 0):

```
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Remove this from textView2